# How can I determine the maximum possible number of threads?

Tags: mysql, max-connections

What factors determine the maximum possible number of threads mysqld will create?

I only care about consideration for mysql and not limitations that may be imposed by the operating system. Further, I only care about Linux, though if you want to include information specific to Windows, feel free.

As far as I can tell, threads can be created for replication, aspects of innodb, one per client connection up to max_connections, with an additional +1 to handle super connections. What else is there, or is that it?

```
threads_max =   max_connections  
              + 1 for super  
              + 2 for replication slave threads  
              + ? for InnoDB ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux for example, whichever is smaller among:

```
grep -F 'Max process' /proc/$(/sbin/pidof mysqld)/limits|awk '{print $3}'
```

and:

```
mysql -e'show global variables like "max_connections"'
```

UPDATE: As you correctly pointed out, we should add at least the background threads to the list. More information below.

As far as your last update is concerned, for InnoDB we have 
[innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-performance-multiple_io_threads.html).

I've just checked and a MySQL 5.5.34 on debian with default values
we have:

```
mysql> pager grep -i thread
PAGER set to 'grep -i thread'
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
BACKGROUND THREAD
srv_master_thread loops: 1 1_second, 1 sleeps, 0 10_second, 1 background, 1 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 2
MySQL thread id 36, OS thread handle 0xa6c32b40, query id 105 localhost root
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Main thread process no. 21508, id 2758552384, state: waiting for server activity
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

And the OS sees:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ps -Lp$(pidof mysqld) |wc -l
18
```

After connecting as root, the thread count remained the same
(the thread count increased when I made another one tough):

```
root@ubuntu:~# mysql -proot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 37
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> \! ps -Lp$(pidof mysqld) |wc -l
18
mysql> show global status like '%thread%';
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                            | Value |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0     |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0     |
| Threads_cached                           | 0     |
| Threads_connected                        | 1     |
| Threads_created                          | 1     |
| Threads_running                          | 1     |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show global variables like '%thread%';
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                     |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| innodb_purge_threads                    | 0                         |
| innodb_read_io_threads                  | 4                         |
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 0                         |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 10000                     |
| innodb_write_io_threads                 | 4                         |
| max_delayed_threads                     | 20                        |
| max_insert_delayed_threads              | 20                        |
| myisam_repair_threads                   | 1                         |
| performance_schema_max_thread_classes   | 50                        |
| performance_schema_max_thread_instances | 1000                      |
| thread_cache_size                       | 8                         |
| thread_concurrency                      | 10                        |
| thread_handling                         | one-thread-per-connection |
| thread_stack                            | 196608                    |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, as I said, this could be version specific, but we seem to have:

- srv_master_thread
- *n* I/O threads (innodb_read_io_threads,innodb_write_io_threads, insert buffer    thread, log thread)
- other background threads (7 in this case: total 18 - 10(I/O) - 1(main)).

So, if you need to do some kind of capacity planning,
I would suggest to check the number of background threads after the startup without user/app connection and add to that:

1. 1 for users with super privilege
2. the value of max_connections
3. 2 x replication slave

Comment: So if I set max_connections to 1, I can expect mysqld to only ever spawn 1 thread?

Comment: Using your answer as a starting point I did a slightly more in depth analysis and came up with this: http://preston4tw.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-many-threads-does-mysql-use-on-linux.html

Comment: @Preston, good job! Thanks for sharing your analysis!

Answer (score 7):

The best way to see current threads (including all foreground and background threads) is now with `performance_schema`.  For example:

```
mysql 5.7.3> select thread_id, name, type, PROCESSLIST_ID from performance_schema.threads;
+-----------+----------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| thread_id | name                                   | type       | PROCESSLIST_ID |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
|         1 | thread/sql/main                        | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         2 | thread/innodb/io_log_thread            | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         3 | thread/innodb/io_read_thread           | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         4 | thread/innodb/io_read_thread           | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         5 | thread/innodb/io_ibuf_thread           | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         6 | thread/innodb/io_read_thread           | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         7 | thread/innodb/io_read_thread           | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         8 | thread/innodb/io_write_thread          | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|         9 | thread/innodb/io_write_thread          | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        10 | thread/innodb/io_write_thread          | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        11 | thread/innodb/io_write_thread          | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        14 | thread/innodb/srv_lock_timeout_thread  | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        15 | thread/innodb/srv_error_monitor_thread | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        16 | thread/innodb/srv_monitor_thread       | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        17 | thread/innodb/srv_master_thread        | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        18 | thread/innodb/srv_purge_thread         | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        19 | thread/innodb/page_cleaner_thread      | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        20 | thread/sql/signal_handler              | BACKGROUND |           NULL |
|        22 | thread/sql/one_connection              | FOREGROUND |              2 |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I believe the background threads are fixed in number (the actual count will depend on some configuration settings such as `innodb_read_io_threads` and the number of `innodb_purge_threads` etc.)  The FOREGROUND threads are one per connection + a potential of `thread_cache_size` on top of that.